# Is it possible to stay overnight at Chicago Airport?

Tags: usa, chicago, ord

I am travelling from Chennai to Phoenix and I have a layover of over 9 hours in O'hare airport. I am travelling on a student visa. I reach at 19:40 local time and my flight to Phoenix is scheduled at 5:00 the next day. Is it possible to stay at the airport without checking into a hotel? Or will I be asked to vacate the premises?

Comment: Depending on whether you can check through to Phoenix or not, you may not be able to re-enter the secure part of the airport and would be sitting overnight in the public lobby.

Comment: What airline is the flight with to Phoenix?

Comment: American Airlines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any question about staying overnight at an airport can usually be answered by consulting the comprehensive [sleeping in airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/chicago_ohare.htm) website. It's probably best to read the reviews on that site to see the experiences of previous passengers there. Since you're arriving from an international flight, you will have to clear security, re-check your luggage if you have any, and you may or may not be allowed through security for your flight the next day. I suspect you won't be allowed through but can't confirm that.

If there has been disruption, apparently the airport sets up cots for passengers. If not, you will have to find a bench or quiet corner to sleep. If you can afford it, you'll obviously be a lot more comfortable in a hotel. Looking on google maps for hotels near the airport, there seem to be *reasonably* inexpensive hotels nearby in the order of $80-$100.

Comment: the web site is a great tip: however it does not, literally, state whether or not o'hare is the type of airport which is open all night or whether it is the type which literally closes late at night for a few hours.

Comment: http://www.sleepinginairports.net/usa/chicago_ohare.htm#hours says it's open 24 hours